Styled Components styles are not applied
I've a react popup which uses styled-component for styling. I'm rendering the react app in shadow dom. Because I didn't want any other css file to modify the popup. It is working on most sites except for this one website, Here it does render the html but not the styles. Any reason why this is happening?
I cannot share the whole code as it's in a private repo and I don't own it.
Here are some code
// src/main.jsx
import { StyleSheetManager } from "styled-components";
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'
import App from './App.jsx'

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  #app-root {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: black;
  }


  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 1;
  }

`

const Popup = (id) => {
  const host = document.createElement("div");
  host.setAttribute("id", "host");
  document.body.appendChild(host);


  const shadow = host.attachShadow({ mode: "closed" });
  const styleSlot = document.createElement("div");
  const renderIn = document.createElement("div");
  renderIn.setAttribute("id", "app-root")

  shadow.appendChild(styleSlot);
  shadow.appendChild(renderIn);


  ReactDOM.createRoot(renderIn).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <StyleSheetManager target={styleSlot}>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <App id={id} hostId="#host" />
      </StyleSheetManager>
    </React.StrictMode>
  )
}

// example component
import styled from "styled-components";
import Form from "../Form";
// ...other imports

const HeaderS = styled.header`
  background: var(--color);
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;

  & .flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }

  & .arrow-con {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    translate: 0 -50%;
  }

  & h2 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  & svg:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    scale: 1.1;
  }
`;

const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <HeaderS>
      <div className="flex">
        <span className="arrow-con"><Back color="white" onClick={props.onClick} /></span>
        <h2>{props.help}</h2>
      </div>
      <Form
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        onSubmit={props.onSubmit}
        Icon={<Search />}
        style={{
          bg: "#fff",
          pd: "12px",
          p_color: "#737373",
          f_weight: "normal",
        }}
      />
    </HeaderS>
  );
};

export default Header;

This is how it looks on normal sites


// But here on this site it doesn't apply the styles

What could be the reason(s) why only on this site styles are blocked or not loaded?
And how can I debug it?

Read for react styled component document 
    import styled from "styled-components";
    import Form from "../Form";
    import { Back, Search } from '../Icons'; // assuming Back and Search are SVG components
    
    const HeaderS = styled.header`
      background: var(--color);
      color: white;
      padding: 12px;
    
       .flex {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top: 8px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
      }
    
      .arrow-con {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
        translate: 0 -50%;
      }
    
       h2 {
        font-size: 1.8em;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
       svg:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        transform: scale(1.1); // Use "transform" instead of "scale" for CSS
      }
    `;
    
    const Header = (props) => {
      return (
        <HeaderS>
          <div className="flex">
            <span className="arrow-con"><Back color="white" onClick={props.onClick} /></span>
            <h2>{props.help}</h2>
          </div>
          <Form
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            onSubmit={props.onSubmit}
            Icon={<Search />}
            style={{
              bg: "#fff",
              pd: "12px",
              p_color: "#737373",
              f_weight: "normal",
            }}
          />
        </HeaderS>
      );
    };
    
    export default Header;


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Setting 'SC_DISABLE_SPEEDY': "true" during the build fixes the issue
I'm using vite so in vite.config.js file adding this fix it
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({

  define: {
    'SC_DISABLE_SPEEDY': "true", // needed to enable vendor prefixing using 'vite build'
  }
});

